# How to generate a list by combination in Python3?

Tags: python, function

I need to make a function that generates a list from a text:

```
text = '^to[by, from] all ^appearances[appearance]'

list = ['to all appearances', 'to all appearance', 'by all appearances', 
        'by all appearance', 'from all appearances', 'from all appearance']
```

That is, the value inside the brackets is supposed to replace the previous word(s), which immediately after the ^. I want to have five arguments to the function, as you can see below...

**My code** (It doesn't work)

```
def addSubstitution(buf, substitutions, val1='[', val2=']', dsym=',', start_p="^"):
    for i in range(1, len(buf), 2):
        buff = []
        buff.extend(buf)
        if re.search('''[^{2}]+[{0}][^{1}{0}]+?[{1}]'''.format(val1, val2, start_p,     buff[i]):
            substrs = re.split('['+val1+']'+'|'+'['+val2+']'+'|'+dsym, buff[i])
            for substr in substrs:
                if substr:
                    buff[i] = substr
                    addSubstitution(buff, substitutions, val1, val2, dsym, start_p)
        return
    substitutions.add(''.join(buf))
    pass

def getSubstitution(text, val1='[', val2=']', dsym=',', start_p="^"):
    pattern = '''[^{2}]+[{0}][^{1}{0}]+?[{1}]'''.format(val1, val2, start_p)
    texts = re.split(pattern,text)
    opttexts = re.findall(pattern,text)
    buff = []
    p = iter(texts)
    t = iter(opttexts)
    buf = []
    while True:
        try:
            buf.append(next(p))
            buf.append(next(t))
        except StopIteration:
            break
     substitutions = set()
     addSubstitution(buf, substitutions, val1, val2, dsym, start_p)
     substitutions = list(substitutions)
     substitutions.sort(key=len)
     return substitutions
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste your current code and the full traceback/error messages into your question?  That way it'll be easier to help you fix the problems with what you've written.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be this (I am skipping the string manipulation code):

```
text = '^to[by, from] all ^appearances[appearance]'
```

Step 1: Tokenize `text` like this:

```
tokenizedText = ['^to[by, from]', 'all', '^appearances[appearance]']
```

Step 2: Prepare a list of all words for which we need a cartesian product (words starting with a ^).

```
combinationList = []
for word in tokenizedText:
    if word[0] == '^': # split the words into a list, and add them to `combinationList`.

combinationList = [['to', 'by', 'from'], ['appearances', 'appearance']]
```

Step 3: Perform the cartesian product using `itertools.product(...)`:

```
for substitution in itertools.product(*combinationList):
    counter = 0
    sentence = []
    for word in tokenizedInput:
        if word[0] == '^':
            sentence.append(substitution[counter])
            counter += 1
        else:
            sentence.append(word)
   print ' '.join(sentence)    # Or append this to a list if you want to return all substitutions.
```

Comment: At the cost of a little more complexity in the parsing/tokenizing stage, you can make the recombining part easier by performing the Cartesian product on all the parts of of the sentence, including the ones that don't have any variations. For the OP's example, the recombination step might be: `"".join(itertools.product([["to", "by", "from"], [" all "], ["appearances", "appearance"]]))`